# Specific String format to NSDate

Tags: string, swift, nsdate

I have this String `2015-02-17T08:53:22.9170000+00:00` and I want to converted to `NSdate`.

The prefered format to print is `hh:mm:ss-dd-mm-yyyy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
let string = "2015-02-17T08:53:22.9170000+00:00"

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz"
if let date = formatter.dateFromString(string) {

   //Now you can format what ever you want, like  
   formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss-dd-mm-yyyy"
   print(formatter.stringFromDate(date))
}
```

Comment: perfect!! i havent seen before a format like"2015-02-17T08:53:22.9170000+00:00". Thanks a lot